# Counting vowels and consonants after entering another string

Tags: java

JAVA:

Write a class with a constructor that accepts a String object as its argument.
The class should have a method that returns the number of vowels in the string,
and another method that returns the number of consonants in the string.
(Spaces count as neither vowels nor consonants and should be ignored.)

Demonstrate the class in a program that performs the following steps:

1. The user is asked to enter a string.
2. The program displays the following menu:

a. Count the number of vowels in the string.

b. Count the number of consonants in the string

c. Count both the vowels and consonants in the string

d. Enter another string

e. Exit the program

I have written the code: when can you check my option d, when I am entering another String, it gives vowels and consonants count 0.

```
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a String: ");
    String input1 = sc.nextLine();

    VowelsAndConsonants vc = new VowelsAndConsonants(input1.toLowerCase());

    System.out.println("\nWhat would you like to do? Enter:\n" + "'a' to count the vowels\n"
            + "'b' to count consonants\n" + "'c' to count both vowels and consonants\n"
            + "'d' to enter another String\n" + "'e' to exit the program");
    char input2 = sc.next().charAt(0);

    while (input2 != 'e') {

        if (input2 == 'a') {
            System.out.println("Vowels: " + vc.vowelsCount());
        } else if (input2 == 'b') {
            System.out.println("Consonants: " + vc.consonantCount());
        } else if (input2 == 'c') {
            System.out.println("Vowels: " + vc.vowelsCount());
            System.out.println("Consonants: " + vc.consonantCount());
        } else if (input2 == 'd') {
            System.out.println("Enter another string: ");
             input1 = sc.nextLine();
            vc = new VowelsAndConsonants(input1.toLowerCase());
        }
        System.out.println("\nWhat would you like to do? Enter:\n" + "'a' to count the vowels\n"
                + "'b' to count consonants\n" + "'c' to count both vowels and consonants\n"
                + "'d' to enter another String\n" + "'e' to exit the program");
         input2 = sc.next().charAt(0);

    }
    System.out.println("Have a great day!");
```

Comment: Your code has many problems. First of all use the ```switch - case``` concept for the options, then java String has many built in string that can help you with this. Such as ```.contains```, ```.equals```, and etc.

Comment: Kumar, it is better on StackOverflow to post a complete, compilable, runnable program, and you could paraphrase the assignment as simply "a program to count vowels and consonants in strings." You'll get a better response if you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well-known problem when you mix the `next()` and `nextLine()` methods of `Scanner`. When you call `next()` it returns the next word up until a newline character, but leaves the newline character in the buffer. The first line of the remaining input is now a blank line.

Then, when you call `nextLine()` it returns all the characters up to that newline; in other words, it returns zero characters, an empty string.

If you are careful to consume the extra newline with an extra call to `nextLine()` after calling `next()`, `nextInt()`, `nextDouble()`, etc. then you can mix the calls without issues, but the easiest thing to do in this case would be to always use `nextLine()` for any input from the user.

Comment: Thank you, this concepts helps me a lot and It works well. From next time I will definitely try to make it clear, and I am really new on this. So I might will be asking lots of questions in coming days. Hope to get helps along clear concept, the same way I got on this. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working program that will do what you are looking for:

```
public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a String: ");
        String input1 = sc.next();

        VowelsAndConsonants vc = new VowelsAndConsonants(input1.toLowerCase());




        boolean flag =true;
        while (flag) {
            System.out.println("\nWhat would you like to do? Enter:\n" + "'a' to count the vowels\n"
                    + "'b' to count consonants\n" + "'c' to count both vowels and consonants\n"
                    + "'d' to enter another String\n" + "'e' to exit the program");
            String input2 = sc.next();
            switch (input2) {
                case  "a":
                    System.out.println("Vowels: " + vc.vowelsCount());
                    break;
                case "b":
                    System.out.println("Consonants: " + vc.consonantCount());
                    break;
                case "c":
                    System.out.println("Vowels: " + vc.vowelsCount());
                    System.out.println("Consonants: " + vc.consonantCount());
                    break;
                case "d":
                    System.out.println("Enter another string: ");
                    input1 = sc.next();
                    vc = new VowelsAndConsonants(input1.toLowerCase());
                    break;
                case "e":
                    flag=false;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("wrong selection please try again");

           }
        }
        System.out.println("Have a great day!");
    }
}


class VowelsAndConsonants {
    String str;
    public VowelsAndConsonants(String str){
        this.str = str;
    }


    public int vowelsCount(){
        str = str.replaceAll("[\\W]", "");  //remove non-chars
        int strLength = str.length();
        str = str.replaceAll("[aeiou]", "");
        return strLength-str.length();
    }

    public int consonantCount(){
        str = str.replaceAll("[\\W]", "");  //remove non-chars
        int strLength = str.length();
        str = str.replaceAll("[aeiou]", "");
        return str.length();
    }

}
```

I hope this helps.